# Unable to create read-only wxComboBox in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a program and as one of the requirements, I need to get a ComboBox to be read-only. I tried using wxCB_READONLY and also wxTE_READONLY. In both cases, my debugger threw the following exception:

"A debugging check in this application has failed.

C:\wxWidgets3221\src\msw\combobox.cpp(422): assert "!HasFlag(0x0010)" failed in GetEditHWND(): read-only combobox doesn't have any edit control."

I'm collabing with my friend who is using macOS and there isn't any problem, running the app over on macOS. Below is some additional info:

- Windows version: Windows 11 (Home)
- wxWidgets version: 3.2.2.1
- gcc, g++ version: 13.1.0
- IDE: Visual Studio Code

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "debug",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\Group7_CS163\\GUI\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\debug\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
                "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\Group7_CS163\\GUI",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\include",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\lib\\gcc_x64_dll\\mswud",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\lib\\gcc_x64_dll",
                "-l",
                "wxmsw32ud_core",
                "-l",
                "wxbase32ud",
                "-l",
                "wxmsw32ud_aui"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "release",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\Group7_CS163\\GUI\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\release\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
                "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\Group7_CS163\\GUI",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\include",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\lib\\gcc_x64_dll\\mswu",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wxWidgets\\lib\\gcc_x64_dll",
                "-l",
                "wxmsw32u_core",
                "-l",
                "wxbase32u",
                "-l",
                "wxmsw32u_aui"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the code I'm using:

In "treebook test.cpp"

```
wxPanel *CreateInsertPage(wxBookCtrlBase *parent)
{
    
    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(parent);
    
    panel->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(248, 247, 245));
    ::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    
    wxBoxSizer* all_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    
    wxComboBox* m_combo = new wxComboBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                                         0, NULL, wxCB_READONLY | wxTE_READONLY);
        
    m_combo->SetHint("Lookup Mode");
    
    // Add items to the combo box
    m_combo->Append("Word - Definition");
    m_combo->Append("Definition  - Word");
    
    // Bind the selection event to an event handler
    m_combo->Bind(wxEVT_COMBOBOX,[=](wxCommandEvent& event)
                  {
        wxString selectedText = m_combo->GetValue();
        wxLogMessage("Selected: %s", selectedText);
    });
    
    
    wxSearchCtrl* searchBar = new wxSearchCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER|wxTE_LEFT);
    searchBar->ShowCancelButton(true);
    
    wxBitmap search_ig = wxBitmap("add_clicked.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY);
    
    wxBitmapButton* searchButton = new wxBitmapButton(panel, wxID_ANY, search_ig, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(30,30));
    searchButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [=](wxCommandEvent& event)
                       {
        wxString searchText = searchBar->GetValue();
        wxMessageBox("Searching for: " + searchText);
    });
    
    sizer->Add(m_combo, 0, wxLEFT, 30);
    sizer->Add(searchBar, 0);
    sizer->Add(searchButton,0, wxLEFT, 5);
    
    wxBoxSizer* sizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxTextCtrl* word = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString,wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,-1), wxTE_READONLY|wxTE_CENTER);
    word->SetHint("Word");
    
    wxTextCtrl* pronounciation = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString,wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,-1), wxTE_READONLY|wxTE_CENTER);
    pronounciation->SetHint("Pronounciation");
    sizer2->Add(word,0, wxLEFT, 30);
    sizer2->Add(pronounciation,0, wxLEFT, 10);
    
    wxBoxSizer* sizer4 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    
    wxBoxSizer* sizer3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBitmapButton* m_edit = new wxBitmapButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_HELP), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(30,30));
    m_edit->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [=](wxCommandEvent& event)
                 {
        wxDialog edit_dlg(panel, wxID_ANY, "Edit meaning");
        
        edit_dlg.SetSize(wxSize(300,200));
        
        wxBoxSizer* change = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        wxTextCtrl* word_change = new wxTextCtrl(&edit_dlg, wxID_ANY, "Your word is ...",wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,-1), wxTE_READONLY|wxTE_CENTER);
        
        wxTextCtrl* meaningEntry = new wxTextCtrl(&edit_dlg, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,-1));
        meaningEntry->SetHint("Enter your new definition here");
        
        wxButton* getMeaning = new wxButton(&edit_dlg, wxID_OK, "Save");
        
        wxBoxSizer* center = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        
        change->Add(word_change,0,wxBOTTOM|wxTOP, 5);
        change->Add(meaningEntry,0, wxBOTTOM,10);
        change->Add(getMeaning,0, wxALIGN_CENTER|wxBOTTOM, 10);
        
        center->Add(change, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER|wxALL,30);
        
        edit_dlg.SetSizer(center);
        edit_dlg.Center();
        
        int result = edit_dlg.ShowModal();
        
        // Show the dialog and wait for user input
        if (result == wxID_OK)
        {
            wxString changing = meaningEntry->GetValue();
            if (!changing.empty()) {
                
                wxMessageBox(wxEmptyString, "Changes saved", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, panel);
            }
        }
        
    });
    
    wxBitmapButton* m_favourite = new wxBitmapButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_TICK_MARK), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(30,30));
    
    wxTextCtrl* definition = new wxTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString,wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800,300), wxTE_READONLY|wxTE_CENTER);
    definition->SetHint("Definition");
    
    sizer3->Add(m_edit,0);
    sizer3->Add(m_favourite, 0, wxLEFT, 5);
    
    wxBoxSizer* sizer5 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    
    wxComboBox* m_dataset = new wxComboBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,
                                         0, NULL, wxCB_READONLY | wxTE_READONLY);
        
    m_dataset->SetHint("Data Set");
    
    // Add items to the combo box
    m_dataset->Append("Eng - Viet");
    m_dataset->Append("Viet - Eng");
    m_dataset->Append("Eng - Eng");
    m_dataset->Append("Emoji - Viet");
    m_dataset->Append("Emoji - Eng");
    m_dataset->Append("Eng slangs");
    m_dataset->Append("Vie slangs");
    
    // Bind the selection event to an event handler
    m_dataset->Bind(wxEVT_COMBOBOX,[=](wxCommandEvent& event)
                  {
        wxString selectedText =m_dataset->GetValue();
        wxLogMessage("Selected: %s", selectedText);
    });
    
    wxBitmapButton* m_wordOfDay = new wxBitmapButton(panel, wxID_ANY,wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_NEW) , wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(30,30));
    
    m_wordOfDay->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [=](wxCommandEvent& event)
                       {
        word->SetValue("Word Of The Day");
        pronounciation->SetValue("pronounce");
        definition->SetValue("Definition of the word");
    });
    
    sizer5->Add(m_wordOfDay, 0);
    sizer5->Add(m_dataset,0,wxBOTTOM,5);
    
    sizer4->Add(sizer2,0);
    sizer4->AddSpacer(300);
    sizer4->Add(sizer3,0);
    
    all_sizer->Add(sizer,0);
    all_sizer->Add(sizer4,0);
    all_sizer->Add(definition,0);
    all_sizer->Add(sizer5, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT);
    
    panel->SetSizer(all_sizer);
    
    return panel;
}
```

In "treebook test.hpp"

```
#ifndef treebook_test_hpp
#define treebook_test_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/aui/auibook.h"
#include "wx/wxprec.h"
#include <wx/combobox.h>
#include "wx/imaglist.h"
#include "wx/artprov.h"
#include "wx/cshelp.h"
#include "wx/utils.h"
#include <wx/srchctrl.h>
#include <wx/bmpbuttn.h>
#include <wx/bitmap.h>
#include <wx/image.h>

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
    virtual ~MyFrame();
    void OnBookCtrl(wxBookCtrlBaseEvent& event);
    void OnShowImages(wxCommandEvent& event);

    void OnAuiNotebook(wxAuiNotebookEvent& event) { OnBookCtrl(event); }


    wxBookCtrlBase *GetCurrentBook() const { return m_bookCtrl; }

private:

    void RecreateBook();
    wxPanel *CreateNewPage() const;
    void AddFlagStrIfFlagPresent(wxString & flagStr, long flags, long flag, const wxString& flagName) const;

    // Sample setup
    enum BookType
    {
        Type_AuiNotebook,
        Type_Max
    } m_type;

    // Controls

    wxPanel *m_panel; // Panel containing notebook and other controls
    wxBookCtrlBase *m_bookCtrl;


    // Log window
    wxTextCtrl *m_text;
 // USE_LOG
    bool m_chkShowImages;
    wxBoxSizer *m_sizerFrame;

    wxBookCtrlBase::Images m_images;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum ID_COMMANDS
{
    // these should be in the same order as Type_XXX elements above
    ID_BOOK_AUINOTEBOOK,
    ID_BOOK_MAX,
};

//insert page
#define DICTIONARY        "Dictionary"

//add new word
#define ADD_NEW_WORD          "Add new word"

//favourite list
#define FAVOURITE_LIST                  "Favourite list"

//game
#define GAME                  "Game"
#endif /* treebook_test_hpp */
```

I'm still new so there may be some info I may have failed to include. Please tell me if there happens to be anything missing.

I've tried:

- using `wxCB_READONLY, wxTE_READONLY, wxCB_READONLY | wxTE_READONLY`

What I expected to happen: the combobox becomes read-only (no editing control)

What actually happened: Debugger threw error:
"A debugging check in this application has failed.

C:\wxWidgets3221\src\msw\combobox.cpp(422): assert "!HasFlag(0x0010)" failed in GetEditHWND(): read-only combobox doesn't have any edit control."

Comment: If you want a read only combo box, why not just use wxChoice.  It has a dropdown like a combo box but is always read only.

Comment: @NewPagodi Hi, thanks for your pointers. I wasn't aware there was something like wxChoice. I used it and it worked :) But is there any chance you know how to fix the error above? Is it something fixable, or can only be worked around?

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick question because `wxCB_READONLY` does work just fine, of course. What doesn't work is calling `SetHint()` on a read-only combobox because such combobox doesn't have a text entry capable of showing a hint, and the assert tells you about this.

To realize this, the simplest thing is to break into the debugger when you get the assert: you will see that it's triggered when the code is inside `SetHint()`, which should hopefully be enough to diagnose the problem (and any similar problems in the future).